# Pointer to struct incrementation

Tags: c

was implementing a singular linked list in C.

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct list_el {
   int val;
   struct list_el * next;
};

typedef struct list_el item;

    void main() {
       item * curr, * head,*track;
       int i;
       head = NULL;
       for(i=1;i<=10;i++) {
          curr = (item *)malloc(sizeof(item));
          curr->val = i;
          curr->next=0;
          if(head!=NULL)
          head->next  = curr;
          head = curr;
       }
       curr = curr-10;

       while(curr) {
          printf("%d\n", curr->val);
          curr = curr->next ;
       }
    }
```

As there are 10 elements in the list, so to make the pointer point to the first element, I tried decreasing curr (pointer to struct) by 10, but this got me half way through the list, the values printed were `5,6,7,8,9,10`.

The size of the struct is 4, whereas the size of the pointer is 2, it seems the pointer is decreased by 2*10=20 bytes instead of 40, is this normal? (as I read that pointer increments/decrements according to the size of its type)

Comment: You cannot use pointer arythmetic on a linked list: the items are allocated separately (with malloc) and so they will not be necessarily adjacent in memory. That approach would only work with an array.

Comment: @Viruzzo why not post as answer? :)

Comment: Done. I was actually just deferring to someone to post a completely correct approach to the problem, but that should be done separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use pointer arithmetic on a linked list: the items are allocated separately (with malloc) and so they will not be necessarily adjacent in memory. That approach would only work with an array.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

First of all, the following insertion code isn't correct:

```
      if(head!=NULL) head->next  = curr;
      head = curr;
```

Basically, the element pointed to by `head` is irrevocably lost.

Secondly, the behaviour of the following code is undefined:

```
curr = curr-10;
```

You cannot move across several `malloc()`ed blocks using pointer arithmetic.

Once you fix the insertion logic, it will become possible to traverse the list like so:

```
for (curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: The `curr` part is in fact what he was asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `curr = curr-10` will not bring you back to the head of the linklist.

Answer (score 0):

As Viruzzo pointed out in a comment, you cannot use pointer arithmetic on elements of a linked list. As the word "linked" implies, there are only pointers linking the items together, they're not required to be located at adjacent addresses.

The pointer arithmetic will simply decrease the pointer by a fixed number of bytes, it will not follow pointers. Your list, being singly-linked, doesn't even *have* previous-element pointers to follow.

Answer (score 0):

`curr = curr-10;` is wrong. It does not perform the operation that you think it does!

To print the contents of your linked list, you need to start from the `head` and go through each and every node until you hit `NULL` (assuming its not a circular list).

```
void display()
{
        NODE * current = head;

        if (current == NULL) {
                printf("Empty list \n");
                return;
        }

        while(current != NULL) {
                printf("%d ", current->data);
                current = current->next;
        }

        printf("\n");
        return;
}
```

And to add new node in the front, you can use the following code snippet.

```
void addfront(int data)
{
        NODE *newnode = NULL;

        if ((newnode = malloc(sizeof(NODE))) != NULL) {
                newnode->data = data;
                newnode->next = NULL;   
        } else {
                printf("Couldn't allocate space for new element \n");
                return;
        }       

        if (head == NULL) {
                // empty list
                head = newnode; 
                tail = newnode;
        } else {
                newnode->next = head;
                head = newnode;
        }

        return;
}
```

To add new node at the rear, you can use the following code snippet.

```
void addrear(int data)
{
        NODE * newnode = NULL;

        if ((newnode = (NODE *) malloc(sizeof(NODE))) != NULL) {
                newnode->data = data;
                newnode->next = NULL;
        } else {
                printf("unalbe to allocate memory to the new element - %d \n", data);
                return;
        }

        if (tail == NULL) {
                assert(head == NULL && tail == NULL);
                head = tail = newnode;
        } else {
                tail->next = newnode;
                tail = newnode;
        }

        return;
}
```

All the above mentioned code snippet assumes, you have `head` and `tail` as global variables.

Hope this helps!